# Log ping and date isn't working

Tags: ping, redirection, batch

```
:START
echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.1 >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.2 >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.3 >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.4 >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
goto START
```

This echos Date and time on my screen only, but not into the file.

How can I get date and time in the txt file too?

Comment: What OS and/or shell is this? The `2>&1` looks *nix-esque, but the use of `%date%` and `%time%` hints at a Microsoft OS. The answer will likely be different depending on what OS and shell you want it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo and ping are two commands separated by "&&".
The way you wrote it, the second command (after "&&") is sent to the text file.

If you want both commands output to be sent to the text file, you can put them inside parentheses:

```
:START
(echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.1) >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
(echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.2) >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
(echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.3) >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
(echo %date% %time% && ping -n 1 192.168.1.4) >> pingReport.txt 2>&1
goto START
```