# Save Ping + time Output in a text file

Tags: ping

I want to made a bat file that made to me a report with ping every 1 second + the time and date.
I use Windows 7 .
I tried to read here but doesn't help to me.

Thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log ping and date isnt working](http://superuser.com/questions/653294/log-ping-and-date-isnt-working)

Answer (score 2):

Same as Linux, output ping command to text,

```
ping 8.8.8.8 > pingy_mac_pingersen.txt
```

Contents of pingy_mac_pingersen.txt;

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=231ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=52

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 51ms, Maximum = 231ms, Average = 114ms
```

I'm not sure about the time function you mean but basically
the *.bat would contain the commands the same way you would issue them in terminal so as an example-- ping.bat ;

```
@echo off
ping -t 8.8.8.8 > C:\pingy_mac_pingersen.txt
```

run in terminal including location of *.bat file in command;

```
c:\ping.bat
```

Comment: I know this command but in addition I want to print the date and time at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest for you to move on to Powershell - Powershell contains a cmdlet `Test-Connection` which will do basically the same thing as ping. `Test-Connection` is there only from version PS Version 3 onwards, you might need to install additional versions.

`Test-Connection google.com | Select IPV4Address, ResponseTime, @{N="Date";E={Get-Date}} | format-Table -autosize | out-file -append testConnection.txt`

And the output is as follows:

```
IPV4Address    ResponseTime Date
-----------    ------------ ----
178.235.206.50           14 2015-12-29 09:35:26
178.235.206.50           16 2015-12-29 09:35:27
178.235.206.50           15 2015-12-29 09:35:28
178.235.206.50           15 2015-12-29 09:35:29
```

Comment: How about Ping statistics?